# Android map api-2 disable click

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm in the middle of migrating one of my app to the Android map V2. I'm showing a marker on the map and don't want to send touch events to the map to change the position/zoom level etc. in the earlier version, i was able to disable touch by setting `android:clickable="false"` in the `MapView` . how can i do the same thing in the Android map V2?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Figured it out myself.

```
mMapFragment.getView().setClickable(false);
```

Answer (score 25):

```
yourmap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
```

Comment: this will however set the marker clickable if present