# How to disable google maps touch events through a layout? (android)

Tags: android, google-maps

Here is a screenshot of my application

[image]

If I touch the legend content, I can still move the map or click markers through the legend layout. Here is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<fragment xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.MapsActivity" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/legend_popover"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:radius="7dp"
    android:visibility="gone">
...
```

I don't want to disable the whole map, I want to disable gestures only on the legend popover. Thank you @antonio for the answer

Comment: yourmap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false); or mMapFragment.getView().setClickable(false);

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873288/android-map-api-2-disable-click

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14893040/3790150

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `android:clickable="true"` to your `legend_popover` layout

Answer (score 6):

Use this

mMapFragment.getView().setClickable(false);

Answer (score 6):

Another decent way to achieve the same.

```
googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
```

Comment: @ManikandanK use `googleMap.uiSettings.isMapToolbarEnabled = false`. (For Kotlin)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Kotlin:

```
mapView.getMapAsync {
    it.uiSettings.setAllGesturesEnabled(false)
}
```